# Can't add thumbnail theme support

Tags: thumbnails

```
<?php

function currentYear(){
    return date('Y');
}

function reisblog_thema_support(){
    //Dynamische titel wordpress
    add_theme_support('title-tag');
    // Thumbnail bij een post
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
);
}

add_action('after_theme_setup', 'reisblog_thema_support');


function reisblog_menus(){
    $locations = array(
        'primary' => "menu bovenaan",
    );
    register_nav_menus($locations);
}

add_action('init', 'reisblog_menus');


//Stylesheet enz
function reisblog_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style('reisblog-css', get_template_directory_uri() . "/1htmlreisblog/css/style.css", array('reisblog-bulma'), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('reisblog-bulma', get_template_directory_uri() . "/1htmlreisblog/css/bulma.css", array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('reisblog-fa', get_template_directory_uri() . "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css", array(), '4.7.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('reisblog-fonts', get_template_directory_uri() . "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu", array(), '1.0', 'all');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'reisblog_styles');
?>
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: What specifically isn't working - the `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');` ? There is a stray `);` at the end of `reisblog_thema_support` in case that's the problem.

Comment: I've just noticed your bottom two wp_enqueue_style URLs have both `get_template_directory_uri()` and an absolute URL to Bootstrap and Google Fonts CDNs. You only need the `get_template_directory_uri()` for relative URIs for files in your theme. (You possibly don't need the leading `/1htmlreisblog/` in your other includes either - check if the generated URLs are correct in the page.)

Comment: yes, add_theme_support('post-thumbnails'); is not working. The stray ); didn't solve it. Thanks for answering.

Comment: did you mean to use this hook? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/